# Resolve Intermittent Performance Issue Due to Parameter Sniffing

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sqlperformance

I've got a procedure exhibiting performance issues due to parameter sniffing. The procedure is costly but generally executes in an acceptable amount of time amid typical load. However, it will periodically perform poorly. When this happens, we see sessions executing the procedure go parallel. We'll see the number of sessions executing the routine start to pile up. We resolve the issue by pulling the procedure's plan from the cache, killing the active sessions, and monitoring for an immediate re-occurrence (like when a bad plan ends up back in the cache).

The procedure is in a typical OLTP database (lots of small DML queries).When the subject query performs poorly, it causes a CPU spike and degrades performance of the associated service. During business hours, the procedure is executed more than 5 times a minute (don't have an exact count). The plan for the procedure is here:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1aEVQJBN

All columns in the query (join and projected columns), are covered by indexes.

Here are the options I'm weighing:

1. We can apply Option Recompile to the problematic select statement inside the routine.
2. We could do a little research and find a parameter value that generates a plan that is generally good for "everything". We'd then add the following OPTIMIZE FOR  to the function. This will incur a little technical debt as we may need to adjust this value overtime.
3. We could introduce branching logic in the procedure. If the parameter value were X or in range-X, we'd execute sproc, and if not, we'd run sproc. Again, incurs a little technical debt.
4. We could change the problematic statement to dynamic SQL. This will cause a plan to be generated for each unique SQL statement. If we get tons of unique calls of this procedure, it could bloat the plan cache.
5. Slap a MAXDOP of "1" on the problematic select statement.

Options I've factored out:

1. We can optimize for unknown. This will change record estimates the density vector, and optimize operations for that.

Have I missed any sensible options? What options make the most sense?

Comment: I'd rule out option 5. That just means you are likely to end up with a bad cached plan that now takes even longer to run as it is forced to run serially

Comment: Have you considered replacing the parameters with local variables in the procedure code?   It's another common way of thwarting parameter sniffing.

Comment: @MartinSmith Noted, and makes sense.

Comment: @tab-alleman Do you have an article on that approach? The parameter changes from call to call. You suggesting I assign the value of the parameter to a local variable then use that in my statement?

Comment: It's mentioned in the mother-of-all parameter sniffing articles... but he says that it's basically the same as "Optimize for unknown", so never mind.   http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#fixexamples

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? If you are on 2016 or better you could turn on querystore and force the better query plan.

Comment: @TabAlleman, I think it is a good suggestion. I've had success at with using variables before too. It is wortwhile doing some investigation Adam to see if it works for you. Take a look at some other [examples](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132816/9936) that might also provide some additional insight.

Comment: @JoeDBA_HAHAHA Good question. Sorry for not providing. I'm using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition. Sorry, no 2016 here.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I really appreciate it. I gave the copying parameters to local variables approach a test - see https://gist.github.com/adamfortuno/32b12e7fda4450517ae772f7c328976f. It gave me an interesting plan. I'll do a little more evaluation, but that option is on the board.